# Is there an example for putting the mediaroutebutton on the action bar?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have it working with the following code on `onPrepareMenuOptions` but it doesn't work well.

```
    MenuItem mediaRouteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_button);
    mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mediaRouteItem.getActionView();

    mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    mDialogFactory = new SampleMediaRouteDialogFactory();

    mMediaRouteButton.setDialogFactory(mDialogFactory);
```

I was hoping to compare it against some code that wasn't written by guessing what to do.

Thanks.

EDIT: I just converted my code to use what is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911796/displaying-the-mediaroutebutton-for-chromecast-in-the-action-bar and had the exact same issues. And if I leave the code with `onCreateOptionsMenu` then the button is always disabled.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "but it doesn't work well". Also, what type of ActionBar do you have?

Comment: It has multiple issues. If I use it on `onCreateOptionsMenu` then it never becomes enabled, even if I call `setVisibility` and/or `setEnabled` by hand. I am making these calls after I check if a route is available and according to `MediaRouter` there are routes available. If I try it with `onPrepareOptionsMenu` it works fairly well however if I rotate the screen after I have connected to a chromecast device, then it goes back to enabled as if it hadn't connected to anything. I am just using the default ActionBar, not the compatibility one or actionbar sherlock.

Comment: I think the issue is that `MediaRouter.Callback.onRouteUnselected()` is getting called as soon as the screen rotates, can't figure out why.

Comment: I guess the problem was my `onDestroy` method, which I copied from the documentation. It has a call to unregister the route.